# Sum of array values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a normal way to calculate the sum of array values in JavaScript?

Like in php - `$sum = array_sum($nums);`

What I found is the following, and btw - doesn't work.

I need the result - `10` and not `235`;

```js
function sum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a,b) {
    return a + b
  });
}

let nums = ["2","3","5"];
 console.log(nums);
 let summ = sum(nums);
 console.log(summ);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to parse string to number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible fix is to coerces the `string representing numbers` to `numbers` with the ***unary plus operator***.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()):

> Unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number

Also, I will change your function definition to be more readable, `reduce()` starts with an `accumulator` of `0` and on each iteration over the array it sums the current revised number to the accumulator.

```js
function sum(arr)
{
    return arr.reduce((acc, num) => acc + (+num) /*Coercion to number*/, 0);
}

let nums = ["2","3","5"];
console.log(nums);
let summ = sum(nums);
console.log(summ);
```

However, you should note the previous won't work if you have float numbers or other values on your array, in that case you can use [Number.parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat) with a more generic approach:

```js
function sum(arr)
{
    return arr.reduce((acc, num) =>
    {
        num = parseFloat(num);
        return acc + (Number.isNaN(num) ? 0 : num)
    }, 0);
}

let nums1 = ["2","3","5"];
console.log(sum(nums1));
let nums2 = ["2","3.345","5.5", "foo", {foo:"bar"}, ["hello"]];
console.log(sum(nums2));
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert them to number using [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). As array contains `strings` so `+` operator will join them not add them.

```js
function sum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a,b) {
    return Number(a) + Number(b)
  });
}

let nums = ["2","3","5"];
 console.log(nums);
 let summ = sum(nums);
 console.log(summ);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

the array has strings, you'll need to parse them to `int`s , use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or `+` to [Cast to Number](https://medium.com/@nikjohn/cast-to-number-in-javascript-using-the-unary-operator-f4ca67c792ce)

```js
function sum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return +a + +b
  });
}

let nums = ["2", "3", "5"];
console.log(nums);
let summ = sum(nums);
console.log(summ);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `+` isn't shorthand for `parseInt()`. Type: `+"123.456"` into your Console and see what you get.

Comment: @ScottMarcus noted, thnx :) , edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

If all the items are strings, they will be treated as concatenation. Also, you should provide an initial value of zero for completeness.

```js
const Operations = {
  ADD : (a, b) => a + b,
  SUB : (a, b) => a - b,
  MUL : (a, b) => a * b,
  DIV : (a, b) => a / b,
};

function sum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(Operations.ADD, 0); // Initialize at zero
}

let nums = [ "2", "3", "5" ];
console.log(nums);

let ans = sum(nums.map(x => parseInt(x, 10))); // Parse strings as integers
console.log(ans);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```